# Tire filtering not working?

Tags: ruby, tire

So, I have a class called Fundraiser:

```
class Fundraiser    
  def search!
    search = Tire::Search::Search.new('fundraisers')
    search.query { all }
    search.filter :range, {id: {gt: 1}}
    search.results
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

When I pry into it and view the "search" variable I get no results

```
[1] pry()> search
=> #<Tire::Search::Search:0x007fb3d9d13938
 @filters=[{:range=>{:id=>{:gt=>1}}}],
 @indices=["fundraisers"],
 @options={},
 @path="/fundraisers/_search",
 @types=[]>
```

Even though I have two Fundraisers with IDs higher than "1"

```
[2] pry()> Fundraiser.all.map(&:id)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've rewritten this every way I can think of. Also of note, if I do a similar filter on say, "created_at" being gt/lt a timestamp I get no results.

Update:

I've added the `query` and `results` part of the search call and I'm not getting results still...

```
=> #<Tire::Results::Collection:0x007f92f3302b58
 @facets=nil,
 @max_score=0.0,
 @options={},
 @response=
  {"took"=>0,
   "timed_out"=>false,
   "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0},
   "hits"=>{"total"=>0, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}},
 @time=0,
 @total=0,
 @wrapper=Tire::Results::Item>
```

Comment: how are you indexing your items?

Comment: From what I can tell, there isn't a direct "mapping" per se, I'm assuming that Tire just indexes everything? I am getting search results without the filter aspect, so I haven't dug into it.

Comment: And are the items with ids 2,3 definitely indexed ? localhost:9200/fundraisers/fundraiser/1 should show the data elasticsearch holds for the item with id 1 (assuming that their elastic search type is fundraiser). You might also want to check the mapping elasticsearch has inferred

Answer (score 0):

You've created a search but you haven't executed it (by calling `.results` on it)

Furthermore I'm pretty sure you'll have to define a query, even if it is just

```
search.query { all }
```

You may also wish to considered using a filtered query, although adding filters at the top level will work too.

Comment: Thanks for your help Frederick -- I've edited the original post with updates.